# How can I use this extended template parser class for CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been searching around for extensions of CodeIgniter's parser class that would add the use of conditional statements in the view files.  The problem is that the [location](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/202220/) that I've found it at doesn't offer any explanation on how to use it and doesn't list anything about the file's author.  Could anyone perhaps share any thoughts on this code?

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * CodeIgniter
 *
 * An open source application development framework for PHP 4.3.2 or newer
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2008, EllisLab, Inc.
 * @license     http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/license.html
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com
 * @since       Version 1.0
 * @filesource
 */

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * MY Parser Class
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage  Libraries
 * @category    Parser
 * @author      Haloweb Ltd
 */

class MY_Parser extends CI_Parser {

    /**
     *  Parse a template
     *
     * Parses pseudo-variables contained in the specified template,
     * replacing them with the data in the second param
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @param   array
     * @param   bool
     * @return  string
    */

    function parse($template, $data, $return = FALSE, $include = FALSE)
    {   
        $CI =& get_instance();

        if ($template == '')
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        if ($include === FALSE)
        {       
            $template = $CI->load->view($template, $data, TRUE);
        }

        if (isset($data) && $data != '')
        {
            foreach ($data as $key => $val)
            {
                if (is_array($val))
                {
                    $template = $this->_parse_pair($key, $val, $template);      
                }
                else
                {
                    $template = $this->_parse_single($key, (string)$val, $template);
                }
            }
        }

        // Check for conditional statments
        $template = $this->conditionals($template, $data);

        // populate form tags
        preg_match_all('/{form:(.+)}/i', $template, $posts);
        if ($posts)
        {
            foreach ($posts[1] as $post => $value)
            {
                if ($postValue = $CI->input->post($value))
                {
                    $template = str_replace('{form:'.$value.'}', $postValue, $template);
                }
                else
                {
                    $template = str_replace('{form:'.$value.'}', '', $template);
                }
            }
        }

        //$template = preg_replace('/{(.+)}/i', '', $template);

        if ($return == FALSE)
        {
            $CI->output->append_output($template);
        }

        return $template;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     *  Parse conditional statments
     * 
     * @access    public
     * @param    string
     * @param    bool
     * @return    string
    */

    function conditionals($template, $data)
    {
        if (preg_match_all('/'.$this->l_delim.'if (.+)'.$this->r_delim.'(.+)'.$this->l_delim.'\/if'.$this->r_delim.'/siU', $template, $conditionals, PREG_SET_ORDER))
        {
            if (count($conditionals) > 0)
            {
                // filter through conditionals
                foreach($conditionals as $condition)
                {
                    // get conditional and the string inside
                    $code = (isset($condition[0])) ? $condition[0] : FALSE;
                    $condString = (isset($condition[1])) ? str_replace(' ', '', $condition[1]) : FALSE;
                    $insert = (isset($condition[2])) ? $condition[2] : '';

                    // check code is valid
                    if (!preg_match('/('.$this->l_delim.'|'.$this->r_delim.')/', $condString, $condProblem))
                    {
                        if (!empty($code) || $condString != FALSE || !empty($insert))
                        {
                            if (preg_match("/^!(.*)$/", $condString, $matches))
                            {
                                $condVar = (@!$data[trim($matches[1])]) ? 0 : $data[trim($matches[1])];

                                @$result = (!$condVar) ? TRUE : FALSE;
                            }
                            elseif (preg_match("/([a-z0-9\-_:\(\)]+)(\!=|=|==|>|<)([a-z0-9\-_\/]+)/", $condString, $matches))
                            {
                                $condVar = (@!$data[$matches[1]]) ? 0 : $data[trim($matches[1])];

                                if ($matches[2] == '==' || $matches[2] == '=')
                                {
                                    @$result = ($condVar === $matches[3]) ? TRUE : FALSE;
                                }
                                elseif ($matches[2] == '!=')
                                {
                                    @$result = ($condVar !== $matches[3]) ? TRUE : FALSE;
                                }
                                elseif ($matches[2] == '>')
                                {
                                    @$result = ($condVar > $matches[3]) ? TRUE : FALSE;
                                }
                                elseif ($matches[2] == '<')
                                {
                                    @$result = ($condVar < $matches[3]) ? TRUE : FALSE;
                                }                           
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // if the variable is set
                                if (isset($data[$condString]) && is_array($data[$condString]))
                                {
                                    $result = (count($data[$condString]) > 0) ? TRUE : FALSE;                           
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $result = (isset($data[$condString]) && $data[$condString] != '') ? TRUE : FALSE;
                                }
                            }

                            // filter for else
                            $insert = preg_split('/'.$this->l_delim.'else'.$this->r_delim.'/siU', $insert);

                            if ($result == TRUE)
                            {
                                // show the string inside
                                $template = str_replace($code, $insert[0], $template);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (is_array($insert))
                                {
                                    $insert = (isset($insert[1])) ? $insert[1] : '';
                                    $template = str_replace($code, $insert, $template);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $template = str_replace($code, '', $template);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // remove any conditionals we cant process
                        $template = str_replace($code, '', $template);
                    }
                }
            }                   

            //print_r($conditionals);
        }

        return $template;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     *  Matches a variable pair
     *
     * @access  private
     * @param   string
     * @param   string
     * @return  mixed
     */ 

    function _match_pair($string, $variable)
    {
        $variable = str_replace('(', '\(', $variable);
        $variable = str_replace(')', '\)', $variable);      

        if ( ! preg_match("|".$this->l_delim . $variable . $this->r_delim."(.+?)".$this->l_delim . '/' . $variable . $this->r_delim."|s", $string, $match))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        return $match;
    }   

}
```

Comment: Interesting Lines of code but I am Clueless what exactly you are trying to Do?

Comment: You can already do conditional statements with plain PHP. Use a template engine like **Smarty** if that is what are you looking for. Also, that code above is pretty slow because it uses the regex engine.